# How to play sixteenth note

Tags: violin

I have been learning violin under a teacher for past 1 year. Now i am being taught sixteenth note. I am not able to count up to it. Like we count 1234 for whole note, 1and 2and for half note, 1and for quater note, 1AandA for sixteenth. 
I have not perfected what i have learned till now. Teaching is done in a fast pace.

I have a slow lazy mind with less concentration and a little mind-hand-eye coordination issues. I play violin at not much fast tempo. Also my bowing arm $ left arm fingers is not set yet.

The problem is now I am not able to read the sixteenth note. I cannot seem to separate the sixteenth notes and play the same in violin.
can anybody share tips on how to learn the sixteenth.

Comment: Eventually you should be able to perform these rhythms while only counting the quarter notes. To practice a new rhythm you might want to count in smaller values (which you seem to always do). Try if you can play eighth notes while counting in quarter notes only. If you can do that, you can also perform sixteenth notes while counting in eighths. Try to listen to how the rhythm sounds and then switch to counting in quarter notes. Everything should sound the same, except you have only half the amount of beats.

Comment: Also, you could try practicing the rhythms by just clapping them. Playing the violin also takes concentration, so if you isolate the rhythm first by practicing it without violin, it should make the rhythm easier. When you know the rhythm, it should be easier to perform the rhythm on the violin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semiquavers (sixteenth notes) are *relatively* quick. Not so fast that they can't be counted. Try imagining the music to have all notes twice as long as they actually are, and count steadily. Now all the 16th notes become 8th notes which you are familiar with. Not fast, not slow.Count in either 1 to 8, or 1 to 4, and tap/clap the rhythm first, a few times. When it makes sense, speed it all up - gradually. Once the rhythm is at a suitable speed, *then* try putting notes to it, maybe first just bowing one note at a time, to understand which way the bow will need to go for each few notes.

Another idea is to count 1e&a 2e&a 3e&a 4e&a for them, so now, a crotchet (1 beat note) lasts for the whole of '1e&a'. And don't think counting is just for kids. We still have to count for each new piece we meet!

This is something fundamental that needs going over with your teacher - far better than getting someone to explain in words on a screen!

Answer (score 1):

Ta-ah-ah-ah.    Whole note.
Ta-ah, Ta-ah.   Half notes.
Ta, Ta, Ta, Ta. Quarters.
Titty titty titty titty, 8ths.
Taffatitty taffatitty taffatitty taffatitty  16ths.

"I have a slow lazy mind"
Please place that in the Excuses Box.  Oh dear, it's full...

Answer (score 1):

Count from the smallest note value up. So if you have semi-quavers make them one count, quavers two counts, crotchets four counts, minims eight and semibreves 16. Dotted quavers three counts, dotted crotchets six counts and dotted minims 12 counts.

You have to count pretty quickly for the tempo of the piece to be correct but as a general guide for new students, you can do it this way.